# cant update using updateExpression on Dynamodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

[image]Here is my data structure -

```
{
      "pk": "USER-12560000000",
      "sk": "USER",
      "data": {
        "name": "George",  //I want to modify the value of this attribute
        "updatedAt": Date.now()  // I want to add this attribute to the data field
      }
}
```

I have been trying this below updateExpression, but for some reason it doesn't even give a clue on whats wrong in cloudwatch. In the below code I am only trying to update the value of the displayName attribute, not sure on the code on how to add an extra attribute. The cloudwatch logs dont print the error reason as well. I have read the documentation on aws also a few other stackoveflow posts. I haven't been able to make this work.

Main Lambda Handler -

```
const updateUser = require('./user-queries/updateUser');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var userId = event.arguments.userId;
  var name = event.arguments.name;
  var avatarUrl = event.arguments.avatarUrl;
 console.log(event.info.fieldName);
  switch(event.info.fieldName) {
      case "updateUser":
          return updateUser(userId, name, avatarUrl);
  }
};

const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
AWS.config.update({ region: "ca-central-1" })
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function updateUser(userId, name, avatarUrl) {
  dynamoDB
    .update({
      TableName: "Bol-Table",
      Key: {
        pk: "USER-12560000000",
        sk: "USER",
      },
      UpdateExpression: `set data = :data`,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":data": {
          "name": "Test"
        },
      },
    })
    .promise()
    .then(data => console.log(data.Attributes))
    .catch(console.error)
}
module.exports = updateUser;
```

This is what gets printed out in cloudwatch along with some billing information
2021-10-09T16:25:15.527Z    b1a1e4cb-6001-415c-82a3-cfdc90413e4e    INFO    USER-12560000000 Sam [www.bol.com](http://www.bol.com)

Comment: How are you trying to run this? As an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Thats right, an I am calling the lambda function from a graphql api

Comment: Your code doesn't have an AWS Lambda handler defined. It isn't a valid Lambda function. Are you including your entire code? What does the Lambda Function's log actually show?

Comment: I have added the lambda function to the original post plus the cloudwatch log

Comment: The downvote was because you didn't provide all the information necessary to debug the issue, including all the code and logs. I think you need to add `await` to the updateUser call. And possibly to the `dynamodb.update()` call as well.

Comment: tried this I get the unexpected token message on the line when I add await

Comment: That means the Lambda function is actually waiting for the DynamoDB call to finish now, and is providing you with the error from DynamoDB, which gets your further along in correcting your code.

Comment: I get the error message on the line before even executing the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UpdateExpression` & `ExpressionAttributeValues` are wrong, they should be:

```
UpdateExpression: `set data.name = :x`
...
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":x": "Test"
}
```

The `Key` object also takes in the keys as a `string` so your `Key` object needs to look like:

```
Key: {
    "pk": "USER-12560000000",
    "sk": "USER"
}
```

---

To update/insert multiple fields, the below will work:

```
UpdateExpression: `set data.name = :x, data.updatedAt = :y`
...
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":x": "Test",
    ":y": Date.now()
}
```

Comment: Tried your answer, it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I have updated the original post to include more information. I am adding the updatedAt attribute, not modifying.

Comment: @Sumchans Check the updated answer - perhaps DynamoDB is confusing `:data` as well so I've changed it - does this work? If not, let me know what the response from the API is

Comment: Sorry ermiya, I just tried the update on the name field alone, that is still not working. The cloudwatch logs doesn't say anything about the error. Adding the snip of the cloudwatch logs.

Comment: @Sumchans I think I know what it may be, check back in a minute

Comment: Ermiya just want to confirm that the updatedAt value doesn't exist in the data attribute. I am trying to add that one through this code.

Comment: That's fine @Sumchans, DynamoDB will add it for you in the second snippet - try the single name update first, once that works the 2nd snippet will also work :)

Comment: was your answer updated?

Comment: @Sumchans Yes, try the `Key` object in my answer

Comment: Yes noticed the change in the Key object, still not working, cloudwatch is the same as posted above.

Comment: The dynamodb.update method is not at all called inside the updateUser function and thats why the cloudwatch logs are not created as well.

Comment: @Sumchans My answer should fix your DynamoDB call - regarding the JS call, you’re not exactly hitting my strongest point there so hope someone can help - I do know it’s definitely to do w async/await & that you’re returning before the request has completed/started - otherwise the logic & request should now be working. So sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the dynamodb.update like below made it all work after all.

```
await dynamoDB.update(params).promise();
```

Here is the full code for anyone who comes across this issue.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
AWS.config.update({ region: "ca-central-1" })
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function updateUser(userId, name, avatarUrl) {
  var params = {
    TableName: "Bol-Table",
    Key: {
      "pk": userId,
      "sk": 'USER',
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET details.displayName = :name, details.avatarUrl = :avatarUrl, details.updatedAt = :updateDate',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':name': name,
      ':avatarUrl':avatarUrl,
      ':updateDate': new Date().toISOString()
    },

    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
  };
  const Item = await dynamoDB.update(params).promise();
  console.log(Item)
}
module.exports = updateUser;
```